# Using LINQ SequenceEqual extension method with occassionally null properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm writing a simple console application that compares two instances of a custom class object. For each property, I'm writing True or False to the console window to show whether each of the objects' properties match.

Some properties, like ProductLines (List property), may be null in one or both objects... or neither. This presents a slight problem for using SequenceEqual, since it doesn't accept null values. **Is there a better way to compare two sequence properties than the code I have written?**

```
// test if either collection property is null.
if (commsA.Last().ProductLines == null || commsB.Last().ProductLines == null) 
{
    // if both null, return true.
    if (commsA.Last().ProductLines == null && commsB.Last().ProductLines == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Property Match:{0}", true);
    }
    // else return false.
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Property Match:{0}", false);
    }
}
// neither property is null. compare values and return boolean.
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property Match:{0}", 
          commsA.Last().ProductLines.SequenceEqual(commsB.Last().ProductLines));
}
```

Comment: Side note - each time you write `commsA.Last()` or `commsB.Last()` you execute query. Even with Linq to Objects this involves creating enumerator, and executing Last()

Comment: Cache the result of `Last()` for both sequences. Otherwise you have a risk to iterate it each time. At least it costs you resources where you can spend 0 instead.

Comment: SequenceEqual *does* accept null values... what makes you think it doesn't? (I've just tested it with a string array and it was fine.)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: It doesn't involve any iteration if the sequence is an `IList<T>`. It's still worth avoiding anyway, but...

Comment: @JonSkeet SequenceEqual throws if one of arguments is null - there is checks `if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first")`. And you are right, there will not be enumeration with `Last()`, but only if source is `IList<T>` (still little overhead exists..)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Ah, I see. Yes, I'd missed the usage. It can handle null values *within* the sequences... but not null sources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd probably add a `NullRespectingSequenceEqual` extension method:

```
public static class MoreEnumerable
{
    public static bool NullRespectingSequenceEqual<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        if (first == null && second == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (first == null || second == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return first.SequenceEqual(second);
    }
}
```

Or using a stacked conditional operator:

```
public static class MoreEnumerable
{
    public static bool NullRespectingSequenceEqual<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        return first == null && second == null ? true
             : first == null || second == null ? false
             : first.SequenceEqual(second);
    }
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Property Match: {0}",
     x.ProductLines.NullRespectingSequenceEqual(y.ProductLines));
```

(The business about whether or not you should call `Last` is slightly separate.)

You can reuse that extension method wherever you want, as if it were a normal part of LINQ to Objects. (It won't work for LINQ to SQL etc, of course.)

Comment: Great answer, Jon. I think your extension method will work best for my application.

Answer (score 5):

You definitely have duplication of `Property Match` result displaying. Display results only once. Move calculation to separate method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Property Match:{0}", 
  IsMatch(commsA.Last().ProductLines, commsB.Last().ProductLines));
```

Like this:

```
public bool IsMatch<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    if (a != null && b != null)
       return a.SequenceEqual(b);

    return (a == null && b == null);
}
```

Comment: @DavidAlanCondit of course, you can make this method as extension, especially if you need to use it often